# Masonry wrapper 100% width too wide on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, responsive-design, jquery-masonry

I'm making use of Masonry on a site, and it's working fine, apart from in the mobile version, the tile is extending over 100% (which it is set to in CSS).

Has anyone had this problem before, or any suggestions how to fix it. What would also work, and be even better, is to totally disable masonry in the mobile version. I have tried removing the class on mobile, but for some reason Masonry is still enabled.

JS

```
var container = document.querySelector('.masonry');
var msnry = new Masonry( container, {
  // options
  gutter: 80,
  itemSelector: '.tile',
  isFitWidth: true,
});

var hodgecont = document.querySelector('.hodgemasonry');
var msnry = new Masonry( hodgecont, {
  // options
  gutter: 50,
  itemSelector: '.hodgeitem',
  isFitWidth: true,
});

$container.imagesLoaded( function(){
  $container.masonry({
    itemSelector : '.hodgeitem'
  });
});

#overviewwrapper {
    padding: @edgePadding;
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 0;
    //max-width: @maxWidth;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: @topMargin;
    //background-color: green;
}
```

CSS

```
#overviewwrapper {
    padding: @edgePadding;
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 0;
    //max-width: @maxWidth;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: @topMargin;
    //background-color: green;
}


.tile {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 500px;
    min-width: 0;
    margin: auto;
    margin-bottom: 50px;

}
```

HTML

```
<div id = 'overviewwrapper' class = 'masonry design' >

  <div class = 'tile'>
    <h2><span>Is Jack Wild?</span></h2>
    <div id = 'aboutmetext'>
      <p>About para</p>
    </div>
    <div class = 'info'>
      <ul>
          <li>+49 ******</li>
          <li>info (at) ******/li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>

***other tiles here***

</div>
```

Comment: Can you possibly post here relevant parts of the code you already have and set up a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) demonstrating your issue?

Comment: Yes, sorry I was meant to post code and completely forgot! I'll do it now. The issue seems to be on my website, I've tried it out on the Masonry fiddles, and I can't replicate my problem, but it can be seen at www.isjackwild.com with a window width of around 320 or below.